# Problem with game-data-packager and Quake 2 mission packs

Tags: games

`game-data-packager` worked great for the basic game of Quake 2.  However when I try to run it on the mission packs, I get scrolling errors of the form

```
src/savegame/savegame.c: In function ‘ReadField’:
src/savegame/savegame.c:577:10: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fread’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
     fread(*(char **)p, len, 1, f);
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further flailing about, it looks like running `game-data-packager` isn't required for the mission packs, at least in my setup. I copied the mission pack folders to usr/share/games/quake2.  Then they run just fine if you issue `quake2 +set game [mission-pack]`.

I'm still a bit perplexed why `game-data-packager` has these options for the mission packs if they aren't needed, but perhaps my config is nonstandard (i.e. I am able to copy the data over directly from a Windows installation.)